# How to charge a laptop without a charger

Tags: charging

my computer's charging port has issues with it. We took it to a store where they fix computers, but sadly they said there is no way to fix this computer. I was wondering what are my other options in order to charge my computer(Asus) with 0% battery. Thanks for reading!

Comment: There are no other options, except maybe buying some kind of external charger for your battery.

Comment: The charging port is part of the motherboard, so the motherboard usually has to be replaced.  It can be very difficult to find the same motherboard as they are usually discontinued before the ports start breaking.  Most computer repair stores don't solder things.  Depending on how back the actual damage is you might be able to find an electronics repair shop with someone with the relevant skills.  I have had it done twice.

Comment: @DavidPostill what specific external charger would do the job here? You think i can be able to charge a computer with a USB Port?

Comment: Depending on the store, motherboards can be repaired, just a matter of finding schematics and part sources (generic parts)

Comment: What is wrong with the charging port?  Be very specific in your answer.

Comment: @amanuel2 I think he means take the battery out and charge it (if your laptop has a detachable battery)

Comment: @amanuel2 Even has you could charge your specific laptop over USB (you cannot) your problem is your device charging circuitry, isn’t working so it wouldn’t work either.  There is no standard for laptop batteries so an external charger would be battery model specific.  I am not aware of any third-part laptop charger, there really isn’t a market for it, considering the fact you typically just charge the battery through the device itself

Answer (score 2):

They lied.  They may not have the knowledge to fix it, but it can be fixed.  Many stores which fix computers do it at the "replace motherboard" level, and are not much good with laptops.  You could find a specialist that handles it - maybe a company which does computer AND CELLPHONE repair.

If the charging port is blown, other then charging the battery on an external charger (if the battery is removable) there are no practical ways to bypass the charging port.

Comment: Will this work? https://www.amazon.com/MAXOAK-50000mAh-Portable-External-Notebook-Most/dp/B00YP823NA?SubscriptionId=AKIAINYWQL7SPW7D7JCA&tag=aboutcom02lifewire-20&linkCode=sp1&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00YP823NA&ascsubtag=4050506%7Cgoogle.com%7C%7C%7C66%2C22%2C83%2C27%2C3%2C9%2C79%7C1%7C

Comment: No. If this would work you could use any general purpose laptop charger. The issue is, I believe, internal circuitry in your laptop.  No one can answer what -if any - device can be used unless we know the exact model of your laptop.

Comment: @amanuel2 Your issue is your battery doesn’t charge all an external battery pack would do is provide a method of charging your laptop